# How to remove passwords from memory in Android WebView. (memory dump)

Tags: android, webview, passwords, memory-dump

I tested the same webpage in chrome and my app.

entered the id/password and got a memory dump (frida3)

Only the ID was found in Chrome.

But in my app, both ID/password were found.

I think my app is the problem because I tested it on the same page, but I don't know how to fix it.

1. **Test data**

   - ID: ABCDE

   - PWD : QWE123
2. **Memory Dump**

    - Chrome browser

      ABC

      ABCD

      ABCDE

    - My App

      ABC

      ABCD

      ABCDE

      QWE1

      QWE12

      QWE123